# unrecognized selector for the property existed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the `YYText` in my project and it cause the crash when I setting some property

```
 _contentLbl = [YYLabel new];
 _contentLbl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 1.0;
```

the app crash as

`[YYLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6e89210a0`

I check and I'm sure this property is defined in [YYLabel.h](https://github.com/ibireme/YYText/blob/master/YYText/YYLabel.h),

I try to print all property to the class by the method `class_copyPropertyList` but I still can not find this property `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`

I'm confused and somebody can explain to me?

Comment: Check whether YYLabel class having public property or function in the name of preferredMaxLayoutWidth.

Comment: @AbilashBalasubramanian yes and it seems I miss some property of the class,what confused me is, it works fine before and also works fine in a brand new project, is it possible that there are some incorrect configuration in the project? The `YYText` is managed by cocoaspods